# Sort List by multiple criteria

Tags: apex, sort, comparable

I have a requirement that I need to sort a list of records by multiple criteria but only proceed to the following sorting criteria if there're still duplicates:

Example:
First sort by Type and if there're matches I must sort only these matches and keep the rest untouched:

```
[
{
    type: "A",
    amount: 1000
},
{
    type: "C",
    amount: 200
},
{
    type: "A",
    amount: 2000
},
{
    type: "B",
    amount: 1000
},
{
    type: "A",
    amount: 1000
},
{
    type: "B",
    amount: 2000
}
]
```

Must sort by type first

```
[
{
    type: "A",
    amount: 1000
},
{
    type: "A",
    amount: 2000
},
{
    type: "A",
    amount: 1000
},
{
    type: "B",
    amount: 1000
},
{
    type: "B",
    amount: 2000
},
{
    type: "C",
    amount: 200
}
]
```

And finally by amount

```
[
{
    type: "A",
    amount: 2000
},
{
    type: "A",
    amount: 1000
},
{
    type: "A",
    amount: 1000
},
{
    type: "B",
    amount: 2000
},
{
    type: "B",
    amount: 1000
},
{
    type: "C",
    amount: 200
}
]
```

Is it possible to accomplish these using Comparable interface?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is.

The naive approach would be to simply nest `if()` statements inside the blocks where the previous criteria are equal.

e.g.

```java
if(field1 < otherObject.field1) {
    return -1;
} else if(field1 == otherObject.field1) {
    // When the first criteria is equal, we move on to check the second criteria
    if(field2 < otherObject.field2) {
        return -1;
    } else if(field2 == otherObject.field2) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
} else {
    return 1;
}
```

There's likely a better way to structure things than using nested if-else if, but if you're only checking two criteria then nesting the if-else if isn't too bad. I'd spend time trying to find a better approach if you're checking >= 3 criteria.

Comment: Winter 24 offers a way to pass the sort nature via a Comparator argument to `sort()` See [Release Notes](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_comparator_collator_interface.htm&release=246&type=5)